# How to choose submit button name using element id in MechanicalSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I need to simulate the submit action on a form that has 2 options for submit button with both the options having the same `name` attribute. Here's how they look using the Inspect tool:

[image]

So, they differ in their `id` and `value` attributes but not the `name` attribute.

The problem I am having is that the `submit_selected()` method in `MechanicalSoup` only accepts Button Name as the parameter:

```
submit_selected(btnName=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

So how can I use this method to uniquely select the appropriate button?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Form.choose_submit](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/blob/master/mechanicalsoup/form.py#L288). This function can receive a BeautifulSoup Tag element, so you can use whatever BeautifulSoup provides to select the right submit button.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use other attributes. For instance, we can use id or value from your example as they are not identical. like so....

## by id

```
my_button = br.get_current_page().find('input', id='edit-save')

br.submit_selected(btnName=my_button)
```

## by value

```
my_button = br.get_current_page().find('input', value='Search')

br.submit_selected(btnName=my_button)
```